# Using FMPP with Gradle

Tags: gradle, ant, build.gradle, fmpp

I am attempting to convert an ant task which uses fmpp over to gradle.  I am unable to get my project to build.  I have the following in my build.xml file:

```
<project name="website">
    <property file="build.properties" />
    <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
    <property name="build.dir" location="build" />
    <taskdef name="fmpp" classname="fmpp.tools.AntTask">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="lib/fmpp.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    </target>
    <target name="dist">
        <fmpp sourceRoot="${src.dir}" outputRoot="${build.dir}">
            <data expandProperties="yes">
                base_url: ${base_url}
                google_analytics_number: ${google_analytics_number}
                mail_user: ${mail_user}
                mail_password: ${mail_password}
                mail_recipient: ${mail_recipient}
                upload_folder: ${upload_folder}
                host: ${host}
                port: ${port}
            </data>
        </fmpp>
    </target>
</project>
```

my build.gradle file looks like this

```
ant.taskdef(name: 'fmpp', classname:'fmpp.tools.AntTask') {
    classpath {
        fileset(dir: 'lib', includes: '*.jar')
    }
}

ant.fmpp(sourceRoot:"src", outputRoot :"build") {
    data(expandProperties: 'yes'){
        base_url = base_url
        google_analytics_number = google_analytics_number
        mail_user = mail_user
        mail_password = mail_password
        mail_recipient = mail_recipient
        upload_folder = upload_folder
        host = host
        port = port
    }
}
```

but when I run it I get the following error

> FMPP processing session failed.
>     Caused by: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression base_url is undefined on line 15, column 47 in data/header.htm.

So it seems like the template variable in the htm file isn't being properly picked up and implemented in my my build.  I am not sure how to get around this.  There are a few gradle plugins for fmpp but have very limited documentation and I am having difficulty getting any of them to work.  If any one has suggestions or a work around it would be greatly appreciated.

*** Update

Here is an example of the htm file that's trying to be applied

```
  <head>
    <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        $page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/js/functions.php');
    ?>
    <title>
        <#if title??> ${title}
            <#else> CompSci Resources, LLC | The Complete EDGAR and XBRL Filing Platform, and more!
        </#if>
    </title>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='${base_url}/js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js'> </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='${base_url}/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>  
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jcarousel/0.3.4/jquery.jcarousel.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jcarousel/0.3.4/jquery.jcarousel-autoscroll.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='${base_url}/js/compsci.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='${base_url}/js/carousel.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='${base_url}/js/readmore.js'></script>

    <link rel='shortcut icon' href='${base_url}/images/littlelogo.png' >
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='${base_url}/css/jcarousel.css' >
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='${base_url}/css/bootstrap.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen, projection' href='${base_url}/css/compsci.css'>

    <style type='text/css'>
        @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
            h2 { font-weight: normal; }
            .csr-services-popper-left { margin-top:11px; }
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Google Analytics   -->

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        //Google Analytics
                    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '${google_analytics_number}']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="language" content="en">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: Try colon `:` instead of equals sign `=` in closure passed to `data`, so, e.g.: `base_url: base_url`.

Comment: I tried that but it gives me the following error

Statement labels may not be used in build scripts.
  In case you tried to configure a property named 'base_url', replace ':' with '=' or ' ', otherwise it will not have the desired effect.  @ line 24, column 19.  base_url: base_url

Comment: I need to have a quick look into my old project which used ant in a similar way. Will keep you poster..

Comment: `base_url` is a property set in Ant, right? If so, you'll need to pull it from the Ant project, as Gradle doesn't have direct access to it. Try `base_url = ant.base_url`.

Comment: doing that gives me the following error --- A problem occurred evaluating root project 'csWebsite'.
> No such property: base_url for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilder

Comment: I have a properties.gradle file where I pull my variables (much like the build.properties in ant).  I load it with -- apply from: 'properties.gradle'

Comment: The `apply from:` function loads build scripts, not properties files. Why not just put this property in the default file "gradle.properties"? That way it will be read automatically.

Comment: gives me the same error when put in gradle.properties

Comment: Did you remove the part where it applies the original properties file? I'm trying it myself right now and it seems to work fine.

Comment: yep, I removed that part

Comment: What do you see in the console if you comment out the whole ant.fmpp task and add `println base_url`?

Comment: I see my variable data as expected

Comment: Very strange. Only thing I can help you with at this point is sharing the pared down version of the script that I'm running. https://gist.github.com/CAustin582/da589cf2347958b90bc9b914a4a31467

Comment: looks like what I have.  I posted the html that's bombing out if it helps

Comment: @EdDunn, please have a look at my answer and let me know if it has helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that both properties read from `gradle.properties` and data properties are named exactly the same. To fix it you need to refer to value hidden under property with `project` instance, e.g.:

```
base_url = project.base_url
```

Have a look at the [demo](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/52762913) I've just prepared. It runs without any errors. If you rename properties in `gradle.properties` you may skip `project`, this is the case for `port2` property - renamed on purpose.

Comment: I get the following error when running the above --- [ant:fmpp] Error
[ant:fmpp] Task aborted: FMPP processing session failed.
Caused by: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression base_url is undefined on line 15, column 47 in data/header.htm.

Comment: I posted the htm file in my main question

Comment: @EdDunn, see the updated repo. [This](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/api/fmpp/tools/AntTask.html#setData-java.lang.String-) method from API inspired me to try this way.

Comment: It just represents template DATA in TDD (textual data definition) format. Could you please accept my answer?

Comment: No problem.  Thank again